# How to use helpers in Hexo source files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, static-site, hexo

I have an about page called `source/about/index.ejs`.  In this page, I'd like to use the `image_tag()` [helper](https://hexo.io/docs/helpers.html) within ejs tags, and other helper functions.  However, if I do, I get the error `image_tag is not defined`, and the same for any other helper function.

I assume this means helpers are not loaded when rendering files in the `source`, only in the theme directory.  It also seems that I can't put this type of page in the them directory and have it render with a template.  Is there a way I can use helpers in rendering source files?  If not, why can't I, or why would it be a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hexo Helpers are not reachable in source files. You have to use it in views.**
1. Create a view in `layout/about.ejs`
2. Add your code in it with helpers tag
3. Create a new page with `hexo new page "about"`
3. Add `layout:"about"` in the front-matter of `source/about/index.md` file.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this is [tag plugins](https://hexo.io/docs/tag-plugins.html).

You'll have to rewrite the helpers you want as tag plugins, but after that they're usable in source files. Check out `node_modules/hexo/lib/plugins/tag` for examples.