# How to implement a tabbed codeblock tag for Hexo

Tags: javascript, node.js, hexo

I am trying to create tabbed code-blocks (as a tag plugin) in hexo but I cannot figure out where to put my js function. I thought I could load the function using [the js helper](https://hexo.io/api/helper.html) but I don't know where to include the helper. I tried, and failed, to add it into the tag plugin. This is the tag plugin code (saved as *testtag.js*):

```
hexo.extend.tag.register('testtag', function(args, content){
  var className =  args.join(' ');

  var result = '';
  result += "<\%- js('\\themes\\bootstrap-blog\\scripts\\tab.js') \%>"
  result += '<div class="tabs">';
  result += '<ul>';
  result += '<li class="li_tab1" onclick="tab(&apos;tab1&apos;)"><a>Tab 1</a></li>';
  result += '<li class="li_tab2" onclick="tab(&apos;tab2&apos;)"><a>Tab 2</a></li>';
  result += '</ul>';
  result += '<div class="contentarea">';
  result += '<div id="tab1">';
  result += '<p>' + content + '</p>';
  result += '</div>';
  result += '<div id="tab2" style="display: none;">'
  result += '<p>This is the text for tab 2.</p>'
  result += '</div>'
  result += '</div>'
  result += '</div>'

  return result;

}, {ends: true});
```

which does work. However, the onclick event of the tags just raises the error that it can't find the `tab` function. Note that the first line of `result` above was my failed attempt to use the helper.

This is my `tab` function, *tab.js*:

```
function tab(tab) {
document.getElementById('tab1').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('tab2').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('li_tab1').setAttribute("class", "");
document.getElementById('li_tab2').setAttribute("class", "");
document.getElementById(tab).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('li_'+tab).setAttribute("class", "active");
}
```

Both *tab.js* and *testtag.js* as saved in the *\themes\bootstrap-blog\scripts* folder.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33741841/1011724) which I though might help but I can't figure out what a view is. I couldn't find anything about views in the Hexo docs.

Comment: Hey man. I'm trying to understand your problem. There is multiple issue in your code. What are you trying to do? I need to know that, to give you an answer that make sens. [views/templates](https://hexo.io/docs/templates.html) are stored in `theme/theme_name/layout`

Comment: I want to make a tag plugin that is a tabbed codeblock. e.g I want to post the same code in a few languages and be able to switch between the languages with tabs For example, something like [this](http://codepen.io/wallaceerick/pen/ojtal) but with code colouring as well. Note that I just found that link right now and since it has no js it might be a good way forward for me. But I'm still interested in the answer to the question as it stands. My list elements are rendered with `onclick="tab('tab2')` so I need to write that `tab()` function but I'm not sure where to put the code for it.

Comment: I'd rather do this in a theme.

Comment: @Leo Can you explain how to do this in a theme? I have found the docs severely lacking...

Comment: @Leo Hey men, I just posted a complete example explaining the process.

Comment: In addition to the phenomenal answer by Louis below, this chat transcript shows more detail on how to implement this and also answers my original question of where do I put the js: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/105190

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are too many mistake in your code so I prefer to give you a full example with explanations.

Here is what we need :

1. A custom tag to build the HTML structure of this multiple codeblock
2. A CSS file to stylize the code block and code coloration
3. A JS script to animate the codeblock (tabs)

## Custom tag : `m_codeblock` (JS server side)

We need to allow user to define :

- a name or a link
- multiple codeblock in this tab, so we defined a tag to separate and list each tab

Here is the syntax :

```html
{% m_codeblock [name] [link] %}
    <!-- tab [lang] -->
        source_code
    <!-- endtab -->
{% endm_codeblock %}
```

and an example :

```html
{% m_codeblock stack overflow https://example.fr %}
    <!-- tab html -->
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Hey dan</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    <!-- endtab -->
    <!-- tab css -->
        h1 {
            color:red;
        }
    <!-- endtab -->
{% endm_codeblock %}
```

**Install these dependencies in your blog folder (not theme folder):**

- run `npm install jsdom --save`
- run `npm install jquery --save`

and here is the source code of this custom tag put in `themes/theme_name/scripts/m_codeblock.js`:

```js
'use strict';

var util = require('hexo-util');
var highlight = util.highlight;
var stripIndent = require('strip-indent');
var rCaptionUrl = /(\S[\S\s]*)\s+(https?:\/\/)(\S+)/i;
var rCaption = /(\S[\S\s]*)/;
var rTab = /<!--\s*tab (\w*)\s*-->\n([\w\W\s\S]*?)<!--\s*endtab\s*-->/g;

// create a window with a document to use jQuery library
require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);

    /**
     * Multi code block
     * @param args
     * @param content
     * @returns {string}
     */
    function multiCodeBlock(args, content) {
        var arg = args.join(' ');
        // get blog config
        var config = hexo.config.highlight || {};

        if (!config.enable) {
            return '<pre><code>' + content + '</code></pre>';
        }

        var html;
        var matches = [];
        var match;
        var caption = '';
        var codes = '';

        // extract languages and source codes
        while (match = rTab.exec(content)) {
            matches.push(match[1]);
            matches.push(match[2]);
        }
        // create tabs and tabs content
        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i += 2) {
            var lang = matches[i];
            var code = matches[i + 1];
            var $code;
            // trim code
            code = stripIndent(code).trim();
            // add tab
            // active the first tab
            if (i == 0) {
                caption += '<li class="tab active">' + lang + '</li>';
            }
            else {
                caption += '<li class="tab">' + lang + '</li>';
            }
            // highlight code
            code = highlight(code, {
                lang: lang,
                gutter: config.line_number,
                tab: config.tab_replace,
                autoDetect: config.auto_detect
            });
            // used to parse HTML code and ease DOM manipulation
            // display the first code block
            $code = $('<div>').append(code).find('>:first-child');
            if (i == 0) {
                $code.css('display', 'block');
            }
            else {
                $code.css('display', 'none');
            }

            codes += $code.prop('outerHTML');
        }
        // build caption
        caption = '<ul class="tabs">' + caption + '</ul>';
        // add caption title
        if (rCaptionUrl.test(arg)) {
            match = arg.match(rCaptionUrl);
            caption = '<a href="' + match[2] + match[3] + '">' + match[1] + '</a>' + caption;
        }
        else if (rCaption.test(arg)) {
            match = arg.match(rCaption);
            caption = '<span>' + match[1] + '</span>' + caption;
        }
        codes = '<div class="tabs-content">' + codes + '</div>';
        // wrap caption
        caption = '<figcaption>' + caption + '</figcaption>';
        html = '<figure class="highlight multi">' + caption + codes + '</figure>';
        return html;
    }

    /**
     * Multi code block tag
     *
     * Syntax:
     *   {% m_codeblock %}
     *   <!-- tab [lang] -->
     *       content
     *   <!-- endtab -->
     *   {% endm_codeblock %}
     * E.g:
     *   {% m_codeblock %}
     *   <!-- tab js -->
     *       var test = 'test';
     *   <!-- endtab -->
     *   <!-- tab css -->
     *       .btn {
     *           color: red;
     *       }
     *   <!-- endtab -->
     *   {% endm_codeblock %}
     */
    hexo.extend.tag.register('m_codeblock', multiCodeBlock, {ends: true});
});
```

Read the comment to understand the code.

> All you need to do is put your JavaScript files in the `scripts` folder
>   and Hexo will load them during initialization.

## Stylize the code block

By default, only the first tab is displayed and others hidden and we did that in the custom tag source code here :

```js
$code = $('<div>').append(code).find('>:first-child');
if (i == 0) {
  $code.css('display', 'block');
}
else {
  $code.css('display', 'none');
}
```

So you just need more css to improve user interface and code coloration. Put this file in `theme/theme_name/assets/css/style.css` and link it to a layout.

## Animate the code block (JS client side)

We need some javascript to animate the tab.
When we click on a tab, all tab contents must be hidden and only the right tab displayed. Put this script in `theme/theme_name/assets/js/script.js` and link it to a layout.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.highlight.multi').find('.tab').click(function() {
    var $codeblock = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
    var $tab = $(this);
    // remove `active` css class on all tabs
    $tab.siblings().removeClass('active');
    // add `active` css class on the clicked tab
    $tab.addClass('active');
    // hide all tab contents
    $codeblock.find('.highlight').hide();
    // show only the right one
    $codeblock.find('.highlight.' + $tab.text()).show();
  });  
});
```

Your issue was the opportunity to build this custom tag and I'm gonna integrate it in the next release of a hexo theme ([Tranquilpeak](https://github.com/LouisBarranqueiro/hexo-theme-tranquilpeak)) that I developed.

Here is the result :
[image: result]

**Check it live on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LouisBarranqueiro/77qyxx6c/)**

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried this but when I run the server it gives me the error `Error: Cannot find module 'jsdom'`. Do I need to install the module first somehow? Also, can you explain how to link something to a layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create inner tags that are read by the parent one.

```
{% code_with_tabs %}
  {% code js title="something" class_name="info" %}
    1. aosjaojsdoajsdoajsd
  {% endcode %}
  {% code js title="something" class_name="info" %}
    2. aosjaojsdoajsdoajsd
  {% endcode %}
{% endcode_with_tabs %}
```

And use a parser to read the generated inner HTML.