# Extending Markdown tags without processing the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, markdown, hexo

I am working with Hexo - a nodeJS based static blogging CMS, I am extending the hexo API to register a new block tag called `tabblock`, see here:

```
hexo.extend.tag.register('tabblock', function (args, content) {
    var tabNumber = NumberOfTabs(content);
    var isTabbed = (tabNumber !== 0);
    console.log("Args: " + content);
    // Where my proper logic should go
    result = '<h1> TAG </h1>';
    return result;
  }, { ends: true });
```

This is the source snippet I am trying to interpret:

````
{% tabblock %}
``` JavaScript
    console.log("Double Tap");
```
``` TypeScript
    console.log("Double Tap");
```
{% endtabblock %}
````

However, the console.log from the function which should be processing that source, outputs this:

```
Args: <!--￼0--> <!--￼1-->
```

??? I Assume this is because the code is being interpreted as code rather than content? So if I wrap the `{% tabblock %}` in `{% raw %}` tags then I get no output at all, however, if I put the raw tags inside the `tabblock`, then I get this output:

```
Args: {% raw
```

How can I get my desired content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```` \``` code ```\ ```` is interpreted by Hexo as a code block, that why it output a messy thing. Try with only 2 or 1 backstick, it will works; like this ``` \`` code ``\ ```

I created a tabbed-codeblock tag for Hexo, you should take a look how I did it. As you can see, I wrapped code with the hexo tag and I use this structure to separate code blocks to avoid conflict with source code.

```
<!-- tab [lang] -->
    code
<!-- endtab -->
<!-- tab [lang] -->
    code
<!-- endtab -->
```

- [Gist](https://gist.github.com/LouisBarranqueiro/c1ba29e7d008d81164ab6173d9850d8b) : source code of tabbed code block tag + JS code to animate the component in the browser
- [SO Question - How to implement a tabbed codeblock tag for Hexo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140300/how-to-implement-a-tabbed-codeblock-tag-for-hexo) : because I created this tag for this question :p Read it, I explained the whole process :)
- [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LouisBarranqueiro/77qyxx6c/)

Comment: message me on stack overflow or on gitter man, if you need detailed explanations or help, it will be easier to discuss :)